# Create user with avatar

Tags: sails.js, sails-postgresql

I want to add an avatar in the user registration, but I don't know how, Please can someone share with me a full example (form, JS front, and JS backend). I'm using SailsJS 1.0 (the stable version) with VueJs.
Thanks in advance .

Comment: I also hope to do this one day soon, will share when I do.

Comment: I hope so to do it

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. Watch these platzi tutorials:

- https://courses.platzi.com/classes/1273-sails-js/10757-uploading-backend-file/
- https://courses.platzi.com/classes/1273-sails-js/10758-uploading-frontend-files/
- https://courses.platzi.com/classes/1273-sails-js/10759-downloading-files/

Here is what the videos tell you to do:

1. `npm i sails-hook-uploads`.
2. In `api/controllers/entrance/signup.js`

   1. Above `inputs` key add a new key/value of `files: ['avatar'],`
   2. In the `inputs` add:

      ```
      avatar: {
          type: 'ref',
          required: true
      }
      ```
3. In the body of the `fn` find `var newUserRecord` and above this add (even if avatar is not required, make sure to do this line, otherwise you will have a "timeout of unconsuemd file stream":

   const avatarInfo = await sails.uploadOne(inputs.avatar);
4. Then in the first argument object of `var newUserRecord = await User.create(_.extend({` add:

   ```
   avatarFd: avatarInfo.fd,
   avatarMime: avatarInfo.type
   ```
5. In `api/models/User.js`, add these attributes to your `User` model:

   ```
   avatarFd: {
       type: 'string',
       required: false,
       description: 'will either have "text" or "avatarFd"'
   },

   avatarMime: {
       type: 'string',
       required: false,
       description: 'required if "avatarFd" provided'
   },
   ```
6. Then create a download endpoint, here is how the action would look for it:

   ```
   const user = await User.findOne(id);

   this.res.type(paste.photoMime);

   const avatarStream = await sails.startDownload(paste.photoFd);

   return exits.success(avatarStream);
   ```
7. Add to the routes a route for this download avatar endpoint.
8. Then you can display this avatar by pointing the `<img src="">` the source in here to this download endpoint.

------APPENDIX-----

----signup.js-----

```
module.exports = {


  friendlyName: 'Signup',


  description: 'Sign up for a new user account.',


  extendedDescription:
`This creates a new user record in the database, signs in the requesting user agent
by modifying its [session](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/sessions), and
(if emailing with Mailgun is enabled) sends an account verification email.

If a verification email is sent, the new user's account is put in an "unconfirmed" state
until they confirm they are using a legitimate email address (by clicking the link in
the account verification message.)`,


  files: ['avatar'],

  inputs: {

    emailAddress: {
      required: true,
      type: 'string',
      isEmail: true,
      description: 'The email address for the new account, e.g. m@example.com.',
      extendedDescription: 'Must be a valid email address.',
    },

    password: {
      required: true,
      type: 'string',
      maxLength: 200,
      example: 'passwordlol',
      description: 'The unencrypted password to use for the new account.'
    },

    fullName:  {
      required: true,
      type: 'string',
      example: 'Frida Kahlo de Rivera',
      description: 'The user\'s full name.',
    },

    avatar: {

    }

  },


  exits: {

    success: {
      description: 'New user account was created successfully.'
    },

    invalid: {
      responseType: 'badRequest',
      description: 'The provided fullName, password and/or email address are invalid.',
      extendedDescription: 'If this request was sent from a graphical user interface, the request '+
      'parameters should have been validated/coerced _before_ they were sent.'
    },

    emailAlreadyInUse: {
      statusCode: 409,
      description: 'The provided email address is already in use.',
    },

  },


  fn: async function (inputs) {

    var newEmailAddress = inputs.emailAddress.toLowerCase();

    // must do this even if inputs.avatar is not required
    const avatarInfo = await sails.uploadOne(inputs.avatar);

    // Build up data for the new user record and save it to the database.
    // (Also use `fetch` to retrieve the new ID so that we can use it below.)
    var newUserRecord = await User.create(_.extend({
      emailAddress: newEmailAddress,
      password: await sails.helpers.passwords.hashPassword(inputs.password),
      fullName: inputs.fullName,
      tosAcceptedByIp: this.req.ip,
      avatarFd: avatarInfo.fd,
      avatarMime: avatarInfo.type
    }, sails.config.custom.verifyEmailAddresses? {
      emailProofToken: await sails.helpers.strings.random('url-friendly'),
      emailProofTokenExpiresAt: Date.now() + sails.config.custom.emailProofTokenTTL,
      emailStatus: 'unconfirmed'
    }:{}))
    .intercept('E_UNIQUE', 'emailAlreadyInUse')
    .intercept({name: 'UsageError'}, 'invalid')
    .fetch();

    // If billing feaures are enabled, save a new customer entry in the Stripe API.
    // Then persist the Stripe customer id in the database.
    if (sails.config.custom.enableBillingFeatures) {
      let stripeCustomerId = await sails.helpers.stripe.saveBillingInfo.with({
        emailAddress: newEmailAddress
      }).timeout(5000).retry();
      await User.updateOne(newUserRecord.id)
      .set({
        stripeCustomerId
      });
    }

    // Store the user's new id in their session.
    this.req.session.userId = newUserRecord.id;

    if (sails.config.custom.verifyEmailAddresses) {
      // Send "confirm account" email
      await sails.helpers.sendTemplateEmail.with({
        to: newEmailAddress,
        subject: 'Please confirm your account',
        template: 'email-verify-account',
        templateData: {
          fullName: inputs.fullName,
          token: newUserRecord.emailProofToken
        }
      });
    } else {
      sails.log.info('Skipping new account email verification... (since `verifyEmailAddresses` is disabled)');
    }

    // add to pubilc group
    const publicGroup = await Group.fetchPublicGroup();
    await Group.addMember(publicGroup.id, newUserRecord.id);


  }

};
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try. But I nedd the form and VueJs code. I will try by myself and I'm coming back towards you.

Comment: @AbdelmajidELHAMDAOUI - the code for that is in the 2nd video I posted above "uploading frontend files" - the course is 10$.